# GTFS Realtime Data Interpretation

Tags: python, python-2.7, protocol-buffers, gtfs

I am trying to interpret the data retrieved from [Translink](https://gtfsrt.api.translink.com.au/), specifically the **network-wide feed**.

The data appears in the following format (Link to live [data](https://gtfsrt.api.translink.com.au/Feed)):

```
1.0’¥ŸË
&TU-4521655-LCBS2014-JAN-FUL-Weekday-01
B
#4521655-LCBS2014-JAN-FUL-Weekday-0108:30:0020140812*555-450$Œð’¥ŸŒð’¥Ÿ"010815$
ŒÌž¥ŸŒÌž¥Ÿ"310108
700117 ¾¥ŸË
&TU-4522611-LCBS2014-JAN-FUL-Weekday-01 
B
#4522611-LCBS2014-JAN-FUL-Weekday-0108:40:0020140812*578-450$»§’¥Ÿ»§’¥Ÿ"311084$#»¿ž¥Ÿ»¿ž¥Ÿ"006511
700089 ­‘¥ŸÇ
&TU-4521583-LCBS2014-JAN-FUL-Weekday-01œ
B
#4521583-LCBS2014-JAN-FUL-Weekday-0108:45:0020140812*555-450"
```

Obviously, some of the data can be read without decoding. The data should be supplying a list of busses with current GPS coordinates. Is anyone aware of how this data can be decoded using Python 2.7? I've been stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: might be useful  http://pygtfs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/schedule.html#module-pygtfs.schedule

Comment: Since the Translink document says it is encoded in protobuf, any text representation is **incorrect and meaningless** (protobuf is **not** a text format; if you have forced the data into text: you have already corrupted it). Have you tried running the **raw binary data** through a protobuf deserializer? the [.proto schema is here](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/gtfs-realtime-proto); the python protobuf api is in the [official google drop](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)